# What is the difference between "enroll" and "reenroll" in the context of Fabric CA?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

In the Fabric-CA Client’s CLI documentation(https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/clientcli.html) , there are two commands named "enroll" and "reenroll" respectively. Could any expert tell me the difference between them? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enroll command is used to enroll the user for the first time with the CA.

There could be cases when a certificate expires or gets compromised (so it has to be revoked). So this is when re enrollment comes into the picture and you enroll the same identity again with the CA to get new certificates.

**Additional Note about Revocation of certificates:**

Revocation can be done for a number of reasons (exactly 10), also when revoking please don't forget to update the CRL(Certificate Revocation List).

Please go through these sections of the documentation for a better understanding of the same:

[Reenrolling an Identity](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#reenrolling-an-identity)

[Revoking an Identity](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#revoking-a-certificate-or-identity)

[Generating a CRL](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#generating-a-crl-certificate-revocation-list)

Comment: I did the experiment before and every time I executed the "enroll" command, a brand-new and different private key and certificate were generated. So if "reenroll" command is executed, does it also generate a new and different private key and certificate? According to what you said, I can understand that the "reenroll" command does not generate a new private key, but only generate a new updated certificate, right? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt code is the best documentation

```
// Handle an enroll request, guarded by basic authentication
func enrollHandler(ctx *serverRequestContextImpl) (interface{}, error) {
    id, err := ctx.BasicAuthentication()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    resp, err := handleEnroll(ctx, id)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    err = ctx.ui.LoginComplete()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return resp, nil
}

// Handle a reenroll request, guarded by token authentication
func reenrollHandler(ctx *serverRequestContextImpl) (interface{}, error) {
    // Authenticate the caller
    id, err := ctx.TokenAuthentication()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return handleEnroll(ctx, id)
}
```

we can see both call `handleEnroll` method. The only difference seems to be that `enroll` uses `BasicAuthentication` whereas `reenroll` uses `TokenAuthentication`.

> // BasicAuthentication authenticates the caller's username and
> password // found in the authorization header and returns the username
>
> // TokenAuthentication authenticates the caller by token // in the
> authorization header. // Returns the enrollment ID or error.

So for security reasons you would call `enroll` first providing your username and password. And then use the token obtained by calling `enroll` to `reenroll` without having to expose your password again. Thus the difference between the two is purely a security measure. And yes, thanks Fabric for making it confusing.